# What are the telltale signs of a bad watermelon?

Tags: watermelon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pick a watermelon at the supermarket?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/914/how-do-i-pick-a-watermelon-at-the-supermarket)

I always pick out watermelons based on the tips that people provide (dried up ends, root area gives in slightly when pressed, heavy for their size, etc.) but often times, I still end up with an overly ripe or unripe watermelon.

So, instead of how to pick out a good watermelon, what "bad" signs should I avoid for 1) an unripe melon and/or 2) an overly ripe one? Many thanks!